# How can we get range of number

Tags: c#, arrays, switch-statement, range

I want to make a range number(for example: 1-10), according to user input in `C#`. 
I have a asp text-box, button. User can enter a number in text-box which is less than 10,000.
I want, when user click on button user get the range of his input value.

For Example - If user enter `"35"` in text-box, he get `"Number Range: (31-40)"`.

but, I have some special condition with making range -

If enter number between -

a) 1 to 50  the length of range is 10 - for example enter number is - `49`, range is `(41-50)`.

b) 51 to 100  the length of range is 25 - for example enter number is - `78`, range is `(76-100)`.

c) 101 to 200  the length of range is 50 - for example enter number is - `135`, range is `(101-150)`.

d) 201 to 400  the length of range is 100 - for example enter number is - `245`, range is `(201-300)`.

and so on........

I used `Switch Case` for this but, I didn't get success in create correct logic to get this functionality.

Thanks for help...Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

one simple method would be to use if and else-if like:

```
if(number < 0)
{
// number below zero
}
else if(number < 10)
{
// range 0 - 9
}
else if(number < 40)
{
// range 10 - 39
}
else if(number < 200)
{
// range 40 - 199
}
else if(number < 1000)
{
// range 200 - 999
}
else
{
// range 1000 -
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite the desired output/logic he wanted

Comment: yeah, it depends on how the ranges will be defined, and wether  they are constant or not. Also if the ranges need further code for something or just to be returned whichever one it is

Answer (score 1):

try this, works without any if/else/switch, just good old math:

```
int x = yourNumber;
int maxRange = 50;
while (x > maxRange) maxRange *= 2;
int range = maxRange / 4 / 5 * 5;
int begin = ((x-1) / range * range) + 1;
int end = begin + range - 1;
```

`begin` and `end` are the beginning and end of your range, i think you can do the rest yourself.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel which is exactly the desired output if you look at b) in the question. or what should it return in your opinion?

Comment: Your solution would assume that the max range doubles each time. But when you use a number like 9984, you would get of `9601-12800`, while the OP specified "Less than 10,000"

Comment: @Tseng he specified that the number inputted is less that 10000. no specifications on the range outputted. the 4 example he wrote follow exactly the pattern my code works for. ofc the ranges could break the pattern. but he state 'and so on..'. therefor my code follows that pattern. plus i assume this is some kind of homework. obviously there should be a low limit like 10000 because most ppl wouldn't be able to create the code i did and would have to copy/paste alot

Answer (score 0):

I guess only the numbers below 101 are specialized, otherwise it seems to meet a particular formula, and one possible solution is like the following:

```
public static int[] GetRagneOf(int value) {
    var x=value>0?(value-1)/50:0;

    var power=Math.Log(x, 2);
    var count=25*(int)Math.Pow(2, power);
    var start=1+25*(int)Math.Pow(2, 1+power);

    if(value<101) {
        if(value<76) {
            if(value<51) {
                count=10;
                start=1+value-(value%10);
            }
        }
        else {
            start+=count;
        }
    }

    return Enumerable.Range(start, count).ToArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for `Enumerable.Range`

```
int num = 35;    
if (num <= 50)
{
    int divisor = 10;
    int quotient = num / divisor;
    var result = Enumerable.Range((quotient * divisor) + 1, divisor).ToArray();
}
else if (num <= 100 )
{
    //I assume you can expand yourself
}
```

Comment: @Jonesy what do you mean?

Comment: Now if you generalize the 50 case in its own function, you'll have a better answer...

Answer (score 0):

Here an example of how I'd do it, since from the initial question it's not clear if the result should be a string, an array of numbers or whatever.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] numbers = { 49, 78, 135, 245, 0, 1, 50, 51, 100, 101, 150, 151, 200, 201, 300, 301, 400};

        foreach(var number in numbers) {
            string result = GetRange(number);
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Input: {0}\tResult: {1}",number, result));
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static string GetRange(int number) {
        if(number <= 50) {
            return RangeByQuotient(number, 10);
        } else if(number <= 100) {
            return RangeByQuotient(number, 25);
        } else if(number <= 200) {
            return RangeByQuotient(number, 50);
        } else if(number <= 400) {
            return RangeByQuotient(number, 100);
        }

        return "Invalid Range";
    }
    private static string RangeByQuotient(int number, int quotient) {
        var lower = ((number-1) / quotient) * quotient + 1;
        var upper = (((number-1) / quotient)+1) * quotient;

        return string.Format("({0}-{1})", lower, upper);
    }
}
```

Results in

```
Input: 49       Result: (41-50)
Input: 78       Result: (76-100)
Input: 135      Result: (101-150)
Input: 245      Result: (201-300)
Input: 0        Result: (1-10)
Input: 1        Result: (1-10)
Input: 50       Result: (41-50)
Input: 51       Result: (51-75)
Input: 100      Result: (76-100)
Input: 101      Result: (101-150)
Input: 150      Result: (101-150)
Input: 151      Result: (151-200)
Input: 200      Result: (151-200)
Input: 201      Result: (201-300)
Input: 300      Result: (201-300)
Input: 301      Result: (301-400)
Input: 400      Result: (301-400)
```

**Update:**
Updated to correctly handle border cases, like 50, 51. etc.